# Bottom bar becomes visible in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm developing a SwiftUI app which users first see a sidebar (Screen A) with multiple tappable options. This view also have a IOS 14 toolbar with bottom placement. Both of the screens use the same application state - singleton data source.

```
.toolbar(content: {
     ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
           Text("Settings")
           .onTapGesture {
                //...
           }
     })
```

When user has clicked an option in the Screen A, it navigates user to a second screen (Screen B) by using standard navigation link.

Then, whenever app presents a sheet in Screen B, an empty bottom bar becomes visible in the bottom of the second screen if user updates the data source in this sheet.

[image: Bottom bar is visible at the bottom of screen]

It seems that Screen A is also updated when user opened a sheet in Screen B and changed the data source and somehow toolbar area in Screen A is affecting Screen B.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/emreoktem/f68c4253df9fad3bb52f858376a42e2e) is the example code as gist.

Any idea about how to avoid this case?

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible code for this?

Comment: post more code so we can know what is the problem

Comment: @Asperi thanks for the responses. I've continued to evaluate the problem and also updated my question according to my new findings. Please also find the example code in the updated question.

Comment: @Asperi do you have a comment about this?

Comment: Provided code does not correspond with the described scenario.

Comment: @Asperi I've checked it again and it seems ok to me. When you run the code, please click on an element on master and go to the second page. then please click on the text at the center of the text then dismiss the sheet. You will see the toolbar becomes visible at the bottom of the screen.